# How does tourism bonus work with international trades?

Tags: civilization-6

When shooting for a culture victory, I keep reading that you need to set up international trade routes to help improve tourism. However only some civs seem to show the +25% tourism bonus after I setup a trade route with them. Even when looking at available routes it says that I will have a +25% tourism bonus on some, but then after the route is created it doesn't actually show that anymore. I have trade routes up with 4 different civs, but only one of them is showing the +25% bonus on my routes list.

Answer (score 2):

The better place to find this information is under the victory screen.  There's a tab for the culture victory, where you can hover over the incoming tourism icon from each civ (briefcase in the second column) and see the +/- that is affecting your tourism with them.

**EDIT: With Screenshots of the suggestion!** Here's what I'm talking about, and this may be a bug.  The trade screen doesn't always correctly state when the trade route is providing tourism.

As you can see in the trade route screen, I have a currently active route with Russia, but the trade bonus is not considered active in the trade route screen.
[image: No Culture Bonus shows on Trade Route Screen]

But, on the Culture Victory screen, it clearly shows that the cultural bonus is active.
[image]